# How do I show the end screen when I touch the enemies in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I’m make a 2D game in unity and I searched for a solution but I did not find anything.

This for a new game in unity

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;            // The speed that the player will move at.

    Vector3 movement;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
    Animator anim;                      // Reference to the animator component.
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
    int floorMask;                      // A layer mask so that a ray can be cast just at gameobjects on the floor layer.
    float camRayLength = 100f;          // The length of the ray from the camera into the scene.

    void Awake ()
    {
        // Create a layer mask for the floor layer.
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");

        // Set up references.
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Store the input axes.
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

        // Move the player around the scene.
        Move (h, v);

        // Turn the player to face the mouse cursor.
        Turning ();

        // Animate the player.
        Animating (h, v);
    }

    void Move (float h, float v)
    {
        // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
        movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

        // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Turning ()
    {
        // Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        // Create a RaycastHit variable to store information about what was hit by the ray.
        RaycastHit floorHit;

        // Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
        if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
        {
            // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

            // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);

            // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
        }
    }

    void Animating (float h, float v)
    {
        // Create a boolean that is true if either of the input axes is non-zero.
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;

        // Tell the animator whether or not the player is walking.
        anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
    }
```

I tried some codes up here but it doesn't do what I want in my game. There is no health.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `OnCollisionEnter2D` to check if your player collides with an enemy. This function triggers whenever the GameObject enters the hit box of another GameObject

For example:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "enemy") {
        // Gameover... show end screen
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to set the "tags" on your enemies in the editor.

For more information check out the links below

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1408186/how-to-check-if-boxcollider2d-collided-with-anothe.html

Answer (score 0):

I'am assuming you are a new user to unity, so Iam gonna help you with the code a bit more than I usually do.

to detect a collision with an enemy in 2d, we use the function `OnCollisionEnter2d` and what it does is basically detects collision in 2d and stores the collision's info into a variable, [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) is the documentation... please read to understand more.

So after you wrote the `OnCollisionEnter2d` function, inside it you would need to write an if statement that uses the `OnCollisionEnter2d` info that is stored in a variable. And checks whether the tag of the other game object is compatible with what you wrote in the code.

then you have to make a function(s) to enable and disable the UI components of your game. Since I don't what are those components, I will not write that code in and I will just write some examples. [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) is some documentation that might help.

here is the code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2d(Collision2d other)
{
 if (other.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
{
  disableEnableUI();
}

}
```

here is the `disableEnableUI();` function:

```
public GameObject restartButton;
public GameObject gameOverTxt;
void disableEnableUI()
{
 restartButton.SetActive(true);
 gameOverTxt.SetActive(true);
}
```